# MeteorJS - adding SlickJS afterChange event

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze, slick.js

Neither of these events are firing when the slide changes:

```
Template.playCarousel.onRendered(function() {
    $("#carousel").on("afterChange", function( event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
        console.log("Slide changed. Now at: ", currentSlide);
    });
});
```

or

```
Template.playCarousel.events({
    "afterChange #carousel": function( event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
        console.log("Slide changed. Now at: ", currentSlide);
    }
});
```

Which is the correct method for Meteor/Blaze?

Any reason why I'm not seeing the log when the slide changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the slick page: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/, if you're using v1.4 or later the bottom example you have is deprecated or at least not suited for MeteorJS.

The top example is what you're looking for but it also has too many arguments as it is written now.

```
$("#carousel").on("afterChange", function(slick, currentSlide) {
    console.log("Slide changed. Now at: ", currentSlide);
});
```

You only need `slick` and `currentSlide` as the arguments. It might not be firing because the event is invalid atm.

Comment: Wasn't using SlickJS 1.4. :( Thanks, Maggie!